# What is the difference between "repeat" and "reprise"?

Tags: differences

> reprise: to repeat the performance of  [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reprise)
>
> repeat: to make, do, or perform again [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repeat)

Is there a difference in their connotations? For example, are both of the following appropriate?

> We shall not repeat/reprise our failure last year.

Comment: The question I would be interested in investigating is, How and when did _reprise_ become a close synonym for _repeat_ in English? In Samuel Johnson's original _Dictionary of the English Language_ (1756), _reprise_ had only one definition—and that was as a noun: "The act of taking something in retaliation of injury." The word has come a long way since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences in both frequency and context.

First, [*reprise* is used less often than *repeat*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reprise%2C%20repeat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creprise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crepeat%3B%2Cc0). Scratch that - *reprise* is rare.

Second, *reprise* is usually used in specialized contexts. Honestly, before you had posted this, I've primarily heard the noun as [a fencing term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_fencing#R), where it describes a renewed attack after an initial attack has failed. Using a Corpus of Contemporary American English search, I realized that the term is used to refer to actors repeating a role. The MW entry may not be clear enough on its own, but [this entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reprise) from Oxford Dictionaries provides some clarification:

> Repeat (a piece of music or a performance)

Music *and* performance? If you take "performance" to mean an acting role rather than *performance* in a more generic sense, [then](https://www.upi.com/Nancy-Cartwright-to-reprise-Rufus-voice-in-live-action-Kim-Possible/8541547921347/) [this](https://www.abc15.com/entertainment/coming-to-america-2-gets-a-director-eddie-murphy-set-to-reprise-role) [usage](https://deadline.com/2019/01/homeland-season-6-casting-nimrat-kaur-numan-acar-return-season-4-roles-spoilers-setting-pakistan-afghanistan-qureshi-haqqani-1202535073/) [makes](http://fortune.com/2019/01/07/meghan-markle-may-reprise-her-role-on-suits-to-earn-millions-for-charity/) [sense](https://www.independent.ie/entertainment/music/buzzcocks-pete-shelley-was-planning-to-reprise-greatest-songs-on-tour-37706482.html). (Links are to five recent news stories using the word in the headline - all usages point to either an acting or musical performance.)

In short, *reprise* is far less common and restricted to contexts that are describing the performing arts. *Repeat* is far more general, and has little (if any) restriction on the actions it can refer to. In your example sentence,

> We shall not repeat/reprise our failure last year.

*Reprise* would only work if y'all were speaking as performers who did not want to repeat your roles because the previous performance last year was a failure. That's a big enough stretch that they shouldn't be treated as interchangeable.

Comment: I totally agree with you after I read more examples (except that reprise is not so rare if you zoom in the ngram plot). I guess I can use it figuratively, but I'm unsure about that. For example, "the general reprised a clever move in the second battle."